# How to implement tags in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) JQuery plugin I can fit multiple labels inside of single input field. Unfortunately Chosen does not have any `<tables>` offering the same functionality inside their table cells. 
Let's say I have a simple one-column, one-cell table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td ondblclick="onTdDoubleClick(this)" tabindex="-1">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  function onTdDoubleClick(elem){
    var element = $(elem);
    if (element.prop('contenteditable')=='true') { element.removeAttr("contenteditable"); deselect(element); }
    else { element.prop('contenteditable', true); element.focus(); }  
  }
</script>
```

When I double click the cell I want the cell to turn into the widget that would allow the user to make the multiple item selections similar to this:

[image]

What would be the best and the simplest way to implement this functionality?

Below is the [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) snippet used to create the widget shown on the image I posted as an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">

<style type="text/css" media="all"> .chosen-rtl .chosen-drop {left: -9000px;} </style>

<select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="18" id="multiple-label-example">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option>American Black Bear</option>
  <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
  <option>Brown Bear</option>
  <option selected>Giant Panda</option>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  var config = {
    '.chosen-select'           : {},
    '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
    '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
    '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
    '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
  }
  for (var selector in config) {
    $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not totally sure where you are going, but drag and drop is a very easy thing to implement, user friendly, intuitive operation.  See [Dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/)

Comment: have you tried https://select2.github.io/examples.html? i dont think it doesn't work when the drop down is in a td

Comment: Try to add input tag on dblclick and then add chosen on that

Comment: Thanks for the link! But I want to implement the "tags" selection inside of the table cells.